# How do you create a code to count the number of characters in an array list? (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, count, character

Let's say I have the array:
[Mary, one, had, two, a, three, little, lamb]
I get how to account for the spaces in this array, but what about the characters in each word? How do I code that out?

Comment: Iterate the array and call the `length()` method in the `String` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Either using Strings array or ArrayList, here is what you need:

In case of Strings list as `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Mary", "one", "had", "two", "a", "three", "little", "lamb"));
```

In case of Strings list as Strings `Array`

```
String[] list = new String[] {"Mary", "one", "had", "two", "a", "three", "little", "lamb"};
```

Then iterate it and get length of each one:

```
for (String str : list) {             
    System.out.println("String Length of '"+str+"' is: " + str.length());       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the array, and count how many characters are in each word using .length()

```
int total = 0;
for (String str: array) {
    total += str.length();
} 
System.out.println(total);
```